# Angular Compilation Error: Deprecation warning

Tags: angular, build, compiler-warnings, deprecation-warning

I have started getting this deprecation warning ever since upgraded to Angular 13.

```
TypeError: message.trim is not a function
at Function.Rule.FAILURE_STRING (/home/app/node_modules/tslint/lib/rules/deprecationRule.js:30:81)
at cb (/home/app/node_modules/tslint/lib/rules/deprecationRule.js:57:53)
```

App works fine but it spits this error every time building the app.

This warning is present even with Angular 14.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try updating to the latest version of tslint

```
npm install tslint@latest
```

Comment: Thanks! I plan to replace tslint with eslint next!